# Can I access azure applications from any device?

Tags: azure, opera-mini

I have read that to use applications present on cloud, the only requirement is a web browser and an Internet connection.

Does this mean that I can access applications on azure cloud from my low end phone that has a low speed Internet connection and an Opera Mini browser?

Are there any minimum hardware or software requirements to be able to access these applications?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure can be used to write web applications and services that can be accessed from any device with an internet connection.

On its most basic level Azure can be used like a normal web hosting service to provide web content for mobile devices.

The minimum hardware/software requirements for the device will be dependent on the complexity of the content provided by the web service/site that is hosted on Azure (this is no different to a web service/site hosted on a traditional platform)